# Why is my code breaking? (NSMutableArray issues)

Tags: objective-c

The following code is breaking, returning '(lldb)' :

```
NSMutableArray *numbersArray;

numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i<34; i++) {
    numbersArray[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
}
int r = rand()%34;

while ([numbersArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]]) { //it breaks here
     r = rand()%34;
}
```

Why would it be?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to add 34 times the number `-1` to the array? You are writing a nice endless loop there since `rand() % 34` will never actually produce `-1`

Comment: Breaks how? It runs without crashing, though I'm not sure what the goal is.

Comment: Please describe what you intend this code to do. Feel free to use pseudocode.

Comment: @JustSid It's suppose to work the other way around, I'm trying to get a random value that is not in the vector. In the beginning there isn't any of course.

Comment: @TomHarrington The app crashes and return '(lldb)' with a breakpoint on the commented line of code. The '-1's where supposed to work with another part of the code, for unsure value, but it is unimportant right now, I can simply leave it empty. The purpose is what I wrote above to JustSid

Comment: Must be something from some other part of the app then, because there's nothing in that code that would crash. David Rönnqvist is exactly right about this code not doing anything useful, too.

Comment: @patric.schenke
CREATE ARRAY OF NUMBERS numbersArray; //to be filled with othercode
CREATE RANDOM NUMBER r BETWEEN 0 AND 34;
IF r IS IN numbersArray, THEN r = NEW RANDOM NUMBER;
REPEAT last step UNTIL r NOT IN numbersArray;

Comment: @TomHarrington The code is the bits that so far mess with the array. Parts of it are from different functions. It's initialized in viewDidLoad method and the random number generator part is from a method associated with a button. I'll go trough the code again, but there's nothing else in the whole project that should mess with it for now...

Comment: thanks. your code does exactly that, as @david-ronnqvist pointed out in his answer. Please make sure you don't have any breakpoints set. You can disable all breakpoints temporarily with a button in XCode: http://howwedid.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/breakpoints.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>You are not initializing your array (on line 1) and are pointing to unused memory. It should be</strike>

```
NSMutableArray *numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

---

What you are doing is different from pointing to `nil` which is safe. If you would have done

```
NSMutableArray *numbersArray = nil;
```

you would have seen that the array was always empty because it was sending a message to `nil` causes nothing to happen (e.g. adding objects to `nil` don't do anything at all).

---

### Update (after your edit):

Your code runs fine. You are probably just not getting what it does.

Your first few lines create an array with 34 values that are all `-1`

```
NSMutableArray *numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i<34; i++) {
    numbersArray[i] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
}
```

You then randomize one integrer value between 0 and 33

```
int r = rand()%34;
```

And then "while" the array of all -1's contain that number you randomize a new number.

Since your first number is positive and the array is filled with all -1's you never enter the body of the loop so your code just steps over it.

```
while ([numbersArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]]) { //it breaks here
     r = rand()%34;
}
```

**I can't really understand what you are trying to do but this is what your code is currently doing. (It works but is quite pointless)**

Comment: Actually I am, I forgot that line of code, sorry.

Comment: I left it empty, but the break remains...

Comment: At this day, I would suppose he's using ARC. So the `nil`-initialization is there by default.

Comment: @EBM I've explained what your code does and it works... it just doesn't make sense.